# Group Chat of Skype in pidgin

Tags: skype, pidgin

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Pidgin 2.10.9, Skype 4.3.0.37 and skype-pidgin 20130613+svn660+dfsg-1.  I am able to do individual chats of skype on pidgin without issues.  However, whenever a group chat is started in skype by somebody else (and I am member of that group), I won't be able to participate in that group chat from skype.  And I see the following messages when I run pidgin --debug :

(11:22:59) skype: Sending: 'GET CHAT 19:fd0b517a127d4e8290360fe778cee977@thread.skype STATUS'
(11:22:59) skype: Received: ERROR 105 Invalid chat name

Any idea how to get it working?

Regards,
Seenu.

Comment: Maybe you have some non-standard characters in the chat's name?

Comment: The chat name is not chosen by anybody and skype internally does it.  If I do "/get name" in the chat windows in skype, I get : [12:48:57 PM] System: name=19:fd0b517a127d4e8290360fe778cee977@thread.skype

And FYI, this problem is for all the group chats that are happening in skype.

Answer (score 0):

now https://web.skype.com allow to use some API
so is possible to use it to connect using pidgin
here is the project:
https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb

bye